# How can I update my profile from HTML form template in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am fairly new to Django and I use Django 4.2. I am having a bit of an issue with updating the info of an already saved user on the edit profile page. This is the form in the HTML template:

```
{% block content %}
<main class=" mb-[200px] z-0  main max-sm:mt-0 ">
    <hr class="border-t-1 border-t-black">
    <div class="my-5 py-3"></div>
    <div class="my-5 py-3"></div>
    <section class="width p-4  bg-white"> 
       <div class="form-c  shadow-md bg-[#bba58f]">
            <form action="" method="post" class="form-control" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="w-[350px]  inline-block shadow-md">
                    <h4 class="h4 text-white font-sen"><b>Edit Your Profile</b></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="my-1 py-1"></div>
                <hr class="border-t-1 border-t-black">
                <div class="my-1 py-1"></div>
                <div class="py-3">
                    <input class=" p-2 w-[500px]  rounded-sm max-sm:w-[300px]" type="text" name="fullname" id="name" placeholder="firstname"  >
                </div>

                <div class="py-3">
                    <input class=" p-2 w-[500px]  rounded-sm max-sm:w-[300px]" type="text" name="fullname" id="name" placeholder="lastname" >
                </div>

                <div class="py-3">
                    <input class=" p-2 w-[500px] border rounded-sm max-sm:w-[300px]" type="file" name="profile_pic" accept="image/*" id="profile_pic" >
                </div>

                <div class="py-3">
                    <input class=" p-2 w-[500px] border rounded-sm max-sm:w-[300px]"  type="email" name="email"  id="email" placeholder="email" >
                </div>

                <div class="py-3">
                    <textarea cols="30" rows="10" class="overflow-auto p-2 w-[500px]  rounded-sm max-sm:w-[300px]" type="text" name="bio" id="title" placeholder="Say something about yourself.."></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="py-3">
                    <button class="bg-white p-2 w-[100px] border rounded-sm max-sm:w-[100px]" type="submit" name="submit_btn"  id="button" >submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>

            
       </div>
    </section>

  
    
</main>

{% endblock %}
```

In the views.py file I have this function:

```
def editProfile(request, pk):
    user_info = Profile.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {
        'uid': user_info,
    }
    old_firstname = user_info.firstname
    old_lastname = user_info.lastname
    old_photo = user_info.display_pic
    old_bio = user_info.bio
    old_email = user_info.user.email 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if ('firstname' in request.POST) and ('lastname' in request.POST)and ('lastname' in request.POST) and ('email' in request.POST):          
           user_info.user.email = request.POST.get('email')
           user_info.firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
           user_info.lastname = request.POST.get('lastname')
           user_info.bio = request.POST.get('bio')

           user_info.user.save()
           user_info.save()
           
        elif 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
          
           user_info.display_pic = request.FILES.get('profile_pic')
           user_info.save()
        


    # print(old_email, old_firstname, old_lastname, old_photo)

    return render(request, 'dashpages/editdash.html', context)
```

As you can see, this function is supposed to get the values of the current form and then replace the values in the database. But this function is only changing the image. It's not changing the other values.

I have tried putting the different request.POST in brackets in the if statement, as you saw above. It didn't work. I have tried to give it just two parameters, yet nothing.

Can someone help me with this issue? What am I doing wrong? How can I successfully create the update profile function?

Comment: why '<form action=""' is empty? 'action' is the link the form's post request will be sent to after the submission.

Comment: what for do you need 'if/elif' subblock of the `if request.method == 'POST':`? what for do you need this `if ('firstname' in request.POST) and ('lastname' in request.POST)and ('lastname' in request.POST) and ('email' in request.POST)`?

Comment: Okay @DmitriyNeledva. You're saying I should have an action URL where th info will be sent to? Okay what if the action is the same page? Is that okay?

Comment: that's ok, you just need to 'catch' post request as you do in your code now, but also you need another return in that 'if post' condition

Comment: @DmitriyNeledva. I got the information from a question on here.

Comment: I guess there is no need in 'if/elif' subblock, you can just get rid of it, and take all information just in `if request.method == 'POST':` condition block

Comment: You can create `forms.py` in the app, there you can write a class that will inherit from `forms.Form` in that class you write all fields you need (all of those you've created in html code manually). then you import the class into app's views, in the function 'editProfile' you create instance of the class, you put it to html with just 2 things: `{% csrf_token %}` and  `{{ form.as_ul }}` and when it 'goes' back to the same views function as post request with data you catch it, validate the data and add it to db

Comment: So that's just the only other way @DmitriyNeledva. I thought that maybe I could have done it differently with just HTML but it would seem that I have to create a forms.py file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253197/discussion-between-dmitriy-neledva-and-theocode).

Comment: `name="fullname" id="name" placeholder="lastname"` your form does not have neither `lastname` nor `firstname` key. Print out all the `request.POST` keys for debugging purpose, fix the form field's _name and id_ values, then build your `if` statement. [placeholder](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) is not an identifier of an element.